# SQLite cursor creates a new .db with the same name as the one I want it to open

Tags: python, sqlite, cursors

I'm trying to use a cursor to open a database and read a table using Python, however I keep getting this error:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: table_name`

I can also see that a new .db file is created with the same name as the one I want to open, except that it's empty.

This has worked before on a different database although my code did not close the connection to that database when I ran it the first time.

Could it be that the connection is still open, and that is why I am unable to run the code on a different database? If so, how can I make sure that connection is closed?

If this is not the case, would it be possible for someone to shed some light on this?

Comment: if the database is **not exists** at your **path** you gave, it will create an empty one.

Comment: Could you post the code that raises this error? Though probably you are getting this error because there's no table called 'table_name' in the db.

Comment: Oddly enough, if i paste the name in it works but if i type it in (and make sure it's correct!) the code throws the same error!